# How to make a diference of money with respect to currency rate movements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to make a diffrence of currency rate movements between May and June expressed in total amount of loan people borrowed in CZK (Czech Koruna) with relation to EUR.
e.g.: People have borrowed from my company money in a amount of 27M CZK (corresponding to 1M EUR) in May, which is only 0.89M EUR in June due to the currency rate movements.

I've come with:

```
    SELECT
    SUM((
       SELECT Rate
       FROM s96.CurrencyRates
       WHERE (YEAR(Date)=2017) AND (MONTH(Date)=5)
       ) * t.ApprovedLoanAmount)
      -
    SUM((
       SELECT Rate
       FROM s96.CurrencyRates
       WHERE (YEAR(Date)=2017) AND (MONTH(Date)=6)
       ) * t.ApprovedLoanAmount)
    AS currChange
FROM(
        SELECT ApprovedLoanAmount
       FROM dim.Contract con
          JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON con.CreateDateID = cal.DateId
       WHERE (cal.CalendarYear = 2017) AND (cal.MonthOfYear = 5)
      ) t
```

which returns:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Any help would be aprreciated.

Comment: What is the column type of `con.CreateDateID`? (I suspect "int") Why do you expect to be able to cast it to a date?

Comment: Yes, it's int. I want to be able set desired date. Perhaps, I should use LEFT?

Comment: I guess you don't want that CreatedDateID column, but some "CreatedDate" value (or other column in that table) that *is* of a date type. Or did you encode a date into that value (int 20170704 instead of date 2017-07-04)?

Comment: Could you provide few rows of sample data and what is your expected result?

Comment: Your CurrencyRates table probably have a rate for each day and therefore your subqueries return 30/31 rows. You are trying to make sum of it and see the difference? Probably not.  Perhaps you want comparison just for end of months?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Yes, you're correct. I want to summarized value of all (loan) contracts made in May and compare to to it's value at the end of the June.

Answer (score 1):

There is few options to change you query.
You can calculate current rates in subqueries and use left join on 1=1.
You can also change your sum statements to:

```
SELECT
((
       SELECT SUM(Rate)
       FROM s96.CurrencyRates
       WHERE (YEAR(Date)=2017) AND (MONTH(Date)=5)
       ) * t.ApprovedLoanAmount)
     -
    ((
       SELECT SUM(Rate)
       FROM s96.CurrencyRates
       WHERE (YEAR(Date)=2017) AND (MONTH(Date)=6)
       ) * t.ApprovedLoanAmount)
    AS currChange
FROM(
        SELECT ApprovedLoanAmount
       FROM dim.Contract con
          JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON con.CreateDateID = cal.DateId
       WHERE (cal.CalendarYear = 2017) AND (cal.MonthOfYear = 5)
      ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your exact tables look, so think of this more like a snippet than copy/paste solution:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(ApprovedLoanAmount) AS ApprovedLoanAmountCZK
, SUM(ApprovedLoanAmountEUR_May) AS ApprovedLoanAmountEUR_May
, SUM(ApprovedLoanAmountEUR_June) AS ApprovedLoanAmountEUR_June
, SUM(ApprovedLoanAmountEUR_May) - SUM(ApprovedLoanAmountEUR_June) AS CurrChange
FROM 
(
   SELECT ApprovedLoanAmount
   , ApprovedLoanAmount * (SELECT Rate
                           FROM s96.CurrencyRates rM
                           WHERE rM.Date = cal.Date -- date of contract?
                          AND rM.Currency = 'EUR' -- if you have other currencies rates in same table
   ) AS ApprovedLoanAmountEUR_May
   , ApprovedLoanAmount * (SELECT Rate
                        FROM s96.CurrencyRates rJ
                        WHERE rJ.Date = '20170630'
                        AND rJ.Currency = 'EUR'
   ) AS ApprovedLoanAmountEUR_June
   FROM dim.Contract con
   JOIN dim.Calendar cal ON con.CreateDateID = cal.DateId
   WHERE (cal.CalendarYear = 2017) AND (cal.MonthOfYear = 5)
) t
```

- Make sure both Rate subqueries return only one row each
- Replace cal.Date and rM.Currency with your exact columns
- Replace cal.Date with '20170531' if you want rate on end of May instead on contract date

Comment: CurrencyRates is in format Date as 2016-12-30, but I don't know how to compare a date with a date. E.g. if I write "rj.Currency = 2017-06-30" it return an error because it can't compare to a int.
Further, cal.Date is int...

Comment: Like I said, I don't know the structure of your tables. You have to adapt query yourself. If you are having troubles with that, then please update your question to provide structure and sample data for all involved tables (CurrencyRate, Contract, Calendar)